# VBA - Run Macro from Word to paste values into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am relatively new to VBA, and am at a loss as to why I cannot paste into Excel from Word.  The following macro ends up pasting the value into Word, even though I think I'm activating the Excel document.
The macro is meant to be run from Word; values from various FormFields then need to be pasted into cells in an existing Excel file.
I searched for a similar issue, though what was returned seemed to be variations of what I am experiencing, and I could not modify those answers to this.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Transfer()

Dim WD As Object
Dim ED As Excel.Application
Dim EDS As Excel.Workbook

Set WD = ActiveDocument
Set ED = CreateObject("excel.application")
ED.Visible = True 
Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
"C:\Users\Documents\AppealData.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
Set EDS = ActiveWorkbook

WD.FormFields("AppNum").Copy
EDS.Activate
EDS.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you run the macro from EXCEL and read the word file and then paste it into EXCEL?

Comment: The Word document will be a form that gets filled out; the aim is to have the user who is filling out the Word form run the macro once the form is filled out, to send values for various formfields to Excel for monthly tracking of the Word form.  At the end of the month, hopefully, there will be an Excel file with all the Word data.

Comment: Ok, can you post up a sample of your word file

Comment: `Selection.Paste` is saying to paste the clipboard to the selection in Word.  I think you want something like `ED.Selection.Paste`.  (You should also be careful with `Workbooks.Open`, which should probably be `ED.Workbooks.Open` to ensure you are referring to the correct instance of Excel, and likewise `ED.ActiveWorkbook` instead of just `ActiveWorkbook`.)  A good rule of thumb is "when you have multiple Application objects, qualify **everything**!"

Comment: I posted the code that I have put into the Word file so far, is that not what is needed?

Comment: WD.FormFields("AppNum").Copy. I'm curious what this is referring to.

Comment: That is referring to a FormField in the Word document; I named that FormField 'AppNum".  This .copy command does work, as when the .paste command is executed, it pastes that value (unintended) into the same Word document (rather than the Excel file).

Comment: @ColeGundersen You don't need to activate or select anything. Just use the objects you defined to copy and paste from the clipboard. You can use `EDS.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial ED.xlPasteValues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Selection` is referring to the current application.  To refer to the Excel application you need to use `ED.Selection`.  But it is a bad idea to rely on `Activate` and `Select` anyway.

I suggest you change your code to:

```
Sub Transfer()

    Dim WD As Document
    Dim ED As Excel.Application
    Dim EDS As Excel.Workbook

    Set WD = ActiveDocument
    Set ED = CreateObject("excel.application")
    ED.Visible = True 
    'Avoid "Activate"
    Set EDS = ED.Workbooks.Open(FileName:= _
             "C:\Users\Documents\AppealData.xlsx")

    WD.FormFields("AppNum").Copy
    'Avoid "Activate" and "Select" and "Selection"
    '"Paste" is a worksheet Method, use "PasteSpecial" for a Range
    'Use "xlPasteValues" to avoid formatting issues
    EDS.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Excel.xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This here should work for you.

```
Sub Transfer()
   Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
   Dim oWB As Workbook

   Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
   Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\AppealData.xlsx")

   oExcel.Visible = True

   Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = _ 
      CStr(Documents("Document1").FormFields("AppNum").Result)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, this works as does another post below.  I appreciate your help!